# php function fgetcsv() gives error while cron job

Tags: php, csv, cron, fgetcsv

The following script works fine on browser. But in cron job it gives an error.

> `fgetcsv` expect parameter 1 to be resource,boolean given

Please help.

**Code:**

```
$handle = fopen("http://www.spc.noaa.gov/climo/reports/today_hail.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $import="INSERT into mytable Values('" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]) . "','$data[1]','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[2]) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[3]) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[4]) . "','$data[5]','$data[6]','" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[7]) . "')";

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());        
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Your description suggests that `fopen()` returns `true` :-!

Comment: You are using windows or Linux? Can you try file_get_contents() insted of fopen?

Comment: @shin I think fopen is better in this case isn't it?

Comment: @user3206125 Yes,You are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be your permissions.

Ensure that your permissions & file ownership are configured correctly, being able to run from the browser but not from cron almost always indicates a permission problem.

Comment: More specifically, cron runs under a different user than your webserver (and PHP implicitly) does. This other user does not have correct permissions for whatever file you are trying to read from.

Comment: It says "expect parameter 1 to be resource, boolean ***given***". As in "please provide me with a file handle resource, _not_ a boolean".

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Thank you sir, So do you still think that the problem is with permissions..

Comment: @user3206125 the boolean is most likely false, due to it not being able to fetch the resource.